# Error installing glpk package "Could not build wheels for glpk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly" on Macbook

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter, glpk

I'm practicing for a linear programming/optimization course I'll be taking in the fall.

Most of the course uses jupyter and part of the course requires me to install a package called 'glpk.' I'd like to install it on my mac since anaconda normally makes things like this a breeze, but so far everything I've tried has not worked.

I've tried:

```
sudo apt install libglpk-dev python3.8-dev libgmp3-dev

sudo pip3 install glpk --no-binary :all: 

pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

pip install glpk --no-cache-dir

pip --verbose install glpk
```

All of these have run into their own troubleshooting problems or have had no effect.

I'll happily listen to any advice or suggestions anyone has to offer, Thank you.

Comment: `apt install` is not a command that works on Mac. You will need to install the GLPK library/headers using something like macports or homebrew (or manually retrieve the lib/headers and specify options to `pip`).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have homebrew installed. Is there a guide for installing it with homebrew or manually retrieving the lib/headers like you said?

Comment: I posted an answer that uses homebrew to install the `glpk` library, and then has you setting build options in your environment so that `pip install glpk` works.

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes you have [`homebrew` installed](https://brew.sh).

```
brew install glpk

# set C linker and include flags so that the pip wheel build can
# find the headers and library

LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix glpk)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix glpk)/include" pip install glpk
```

This should allow the `glpk` module to build.